# Delphi Regular Expression Writing

Tags: regex, email, delphi

I am not very fluent in regular expressions with Delphi and am wondering if anyone can spot the issue in my current expression. I would like the expression to also include the + character when searching for valid emails. Can anyone give me a hand with this? TIA

Expression is this

```
TRegEx.Create('[_a-zA-Z\d\-\.]+@[_a-zA-Z\d\-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z\d\-]+)+', [roIgnoreCase, roSingleline])
```

Comment: The character classes are not matching a `+`. You could add it `[_a-zA-Z\d.+-]+@(?:[_a-zA-Z\d+-]+\.)+[_a-zA-Z\d-]+`

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `+` to the first 2 character classes. Note that you don't have to escape the `.` in the character class and you can move the `-` to the end.

```
[_a-zA-Z\d.+-]+@(?:[_a-zA-Z\d+-]+\.)+[_a-zA-Z\d-]+
```

Or perhaps a shorter variant, not matching a dot at the start and end.

```
[\w+]+(?:\.[\w+-])*@(?:[\w+-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```